# Can't send IdentityUser id throw ajax to controller MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, get

I try to send user id,which looks like this `0da7deb4-ed67-4ec1-9ef0-75e4e583df5c`.Type of id is string.Model looks like this.

```
  public class User :IdentityUser
    {     
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

from view i try to send model of id User.By using following jquery code.

```
   <script>
         $('.editProfile').click(function () {
             $.get("/Auth/EditProfile", {userid: @Model.Id}, //function Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
function (PartialView) {
                $('#showProduct').empty();
                $('#showProduct').html(PartialView);
                $('#showProduct').show(PartialView);
            })
        });    
     </script>
```

I try to send it to controller which looks like this.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditProfile(string userid)
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

When i run application in script i get next error.`function Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` .With other string everything is ok.Also i tried to use  `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Just for testing purposes...if you hardcode the value of the userid, the code works, right?

Comment: Try this     $.get("/Auth/EditProfile", {userid: '@Model.Id'}

Comment: If i use this code `   $.get("/Auth/EditProfile", { userid: "fa999e78-ed49-4313-aa6c-eff3414545c0" }, function (PartialView) {
            $('#showProduct').empty();
            $('#showProduct').html(PartialView);
            $('#showProduct').show(PartialView);` everything is ok.

Comment: Paul it works,thanks.